# Is there a way to see which papers have used a particular R package?

Tags: citations, writing, reproducible-research

I'm a new user of an R package (tidy text mining) and I'd like to see what papers have used this package as examples for the kind of things I can do with it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Best suggestion I have is read the help file - usually has examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Sometimes (not often) papers will formally cite the package.
- This is more likely to work if the authors have published a peer-reviewed paper that describes the package; it makes it easier to cite/more likely to be cited. In the case of the [tidytext package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=tidytext) (which may or may not be the package you're referring to), you can find the citation info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/citation.html). More generally, try `citation("package_name")` within R. On Google Scholar, [this page](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?cites=14258410385410868048&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) lists the articles that cite Silge and Robinson 2016.
- Or you can use Google Scholar, which does a full-text search and may pick up the name from papers that mention it even if they haven't formally cited it.

---

Silge, Julia, and David Robinson. “Tidytext: Text Mining and Analysis Using Tidy Data Principles in R.” Journal of Open Source Software 1, no. 3 (July 11, 2016): 37. https://doi.org/10.21105/joss.00037.

Comment: Great, thanks so so much!!